# HTML Table (Bootstrap) scales disproportionally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for some content on my website. The fact is, when creating a table, bootstrap is running my content a little bit. Note: When I click a row in the table, images or numbers will appear (JS).

Here's how the table looks now:

[image]

This happens when I click something. I wanted my table to be like this always (squared, fits well in the screen):

[image]

If a image appears, the table will scale... The problem is the cells scale incorrectly with the content inside:

[image]

Is there a way of adapting bootstrap responsiveness with square cells? Or if necessary, disable it? I've tried many examples, already lost ~1 hour here.

Internal CSS:

```
td {
    height: 30px; /* already tried changing values */
    width: 30px; /* doesn't even get squared */
    /* shadow stuff here */
    border-radius: 2px;
    /* background stuff here */
}

table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 3px;
    width: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="game-container">
    <center>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-nonfluid" id="game"></table>
        </div>
    </center>
    <span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>
</div>
```

EDIT: Used line-height.

Comment: can you show us the html too and a fiddle?

Comment: Edited with HTML. I will try to attach a fiddle example.

Comment: I think I know the solution I just want to be able to test it before.

Comment: Fixed with line-height, now only need to find a way to prevent width stretch.